# Recurrence relationship where the difference of two consecutive terms is polynomial. Solution by generating functions.

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have this recurrence relation

$$h_{n} = h_{n-1} + 4n(n-1) \ \text{for} \ n \geq 1 \ \text{with} \ h_{0} = 0, h_{1} = 0$$

I am asked to find $h_{9}$.

I have attempted to solve this by generating functions and ended up with a closed form solution as:
$g(x) = \frac{4x}{(1-x)^3} - \frac{4x}{(1-x)^2}$
I feel like this is correct, though I'm not totally sure. I then rewrote these as infinite sums so I can find the coefficient of $x^n$ more easily:
$4x \Sigma^{\infty}_{n=0}\binom{n+2}{2}x^n - 4x\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=0}nx^n$
for every value of $n$ the coefficient is $+4$ more than the actual answer, I've looked at my working for a while but not sure how the answer is so close to the solution?
Thanks

Comment: Likely the error is in your calculations of $g$, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Your $g$ simplifies further to $g(x) = \frac{4x^3}{(1-x)^3}$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title. I wish you agree with it. Indeed, it's not good to place big formulas in the titles (in particular for the retrieval of the questions). It's better to place them inside the text of the question.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks, I'll keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my mistake, it was in the second series, the coefficient of $x^n$ is $n+1$ not $n$!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the generating method which is often used for much harder problem. For this one, observer that: $h_n = (h_n - h_{n-1})+(h_{n-1} - h_{n-2})+...+(h_1 - h_0) + h_0 = 4n^2 - 4n + 4(n-1)^2 - 4(n-1) +...+ 4\cdot 2^2 - 4\cdot 2+4\cdot 1^2 - 4\cdot 1+0= 4(1^2+2^2+...+n^2) -4(1+2+...+n)= 4\cdot \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-4\cdot \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$. From this you can find any term and just plug $n = 9$ in the formula to get $h_9$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I realise it's easier to solve with other methods, I forgot to state the question wants me to do it via generating functions.